# web api internal error 500

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api

I am using the laatest version of web api.
I am returning a `IQuerable` value and i am getting this error:

```
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation=QueryableAttribute.ActionExecuted, Status=200 (OK), Exception=System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateStructuralTypeBody(EdmStructuredType type, IStructuralTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateEntityTypeBody(EdmEntityType type, IEntityTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateEdmTypeBody(IStructuralTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.<GetEdmTypes>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.BuildEdmModel(String containerNamespace, String containerName, IEnumerable`1 entityTypeConfigurations, IEnumerable`1 entitySetConfigurations)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetEdmModel>b__0(Object _)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.GetEdmModel(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type entityClrType)
   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionFilterAttributeTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<OnActionExecuted>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation=InteractionDataController.ExecuteAsync, Exception=System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateStructuralTypeBody(EdmStructuredType type, IStructuralTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateEntityTypeBody(EdmEntityType type, IEntityTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.CreateEdmTypeBody(IStructuralTypeConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.<GetEdmTypes>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.BuildEdmModel(String containerNamespace, String containerName, IEnumerable`1 entityTypeConfigurations, IEnumerable`1 entitySetConfigurations)
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetEdmModel>b__0(Object _)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.GetEdmModel(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type entityClrType)
   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionFilterAttributeTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<OnActionExecuted>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionFilterAttributeTracer.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)
```

Can someone explain me what the problem is ?

Comment: Did you ever found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error. I traced it down to when ODataModelBuilder calls GetEdmModel().  I'm using ODataConventionModelBuilder and I'm declaring EntitySets to create my model. In my case, I have a parent class with a child collection. I tried different types of collections, IList, List, ICollection, IEnumerable, and I continued to get this error. I know this isn't the best solution, but I declare the child collection as object. I assign the collection as IEnumerable using Linq. I'll keep looking into this, but at least I can continue with my project. I'll have to keep researching the ODataConventionModelBuilder. I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

-Jason

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in WebApi.OData package (0.1.0-alpha-120815). See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/394626